# Stop NSRunLoop running until date

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsrunloop

I'm working on a game with main menu and the game itself.

In the game, I'm using this code:

```
for (i = 20; i > 0; i--)
{
        // Do something...
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
}
```

There is no problem with the code, but if I go out to the menu (modal segue), the loop continues to run even if I go back to the game, and it causes lots of problems.
How can i stop it?

Edit: from some reason this answer not working for me :

```
CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a couple seconds haha